# Domain squatting

Tags: domains

I'm currently working for a design firm (we'll call them Acme Design), and we own the domain name acmedesign.co.uk (have done since 2008). The name isn't trademarked.

I've just been contacted by another design agency about 2 miles away from us (we'll call them Foobar Media, ie. completely different) whose site is foobarmedia.co.uk - they've just registered acmedesign.com and acme-design.co.uk and are trying to sell them on to us.

At present, the domains both point to Foobar Media's site, so if any clients type the wrong version of the domain into their browser, effectively trying to drive our clients to themselves.

Is there anything we can do about this legally (ICANN UDRP, etc) or is it just a case of "tough luck"?

Comment: Marked it as duplicate because it's almost similar (they hadn't trademarked it at the time of posting)

Comment: As I understand it this form of cybersquatting is illegal, however persuing action through courts / resolution processes can be time consuming and expensive.

Comment: Well, this is just a case of tough luck. You should've trademarked your domain name I'm afraid.

Comment: I suspect that a trademark in the U.K. is something like in the U.S. and follows some similar laws. In this case, you do have a clear cut case of a trademark violation if: one, you have been operating under the trademark for a substantial period of time, and two, your trademark is easily recognized as being yours. The fact that they contacted you is clear malicious intent to usurp your rights to your trademark whether you intended to register the domain name or not. In the U.S., they would be liable for damages and would have to forfeit any trademarked property including the domain name.

Comment: @closetnoc it's not a registered trademark

Comment: Trademark law and copyright law are somewhat similar in that you do not have to register anything to have rights. Operating a business under a name gives you certain rights. If that business becomes nationally known, or globally known, then those rights expand. But if you are *The Corner Bar* then any claim would be difficult. You do not have to register a business name or a domain name to have trademark rights but it does help.